# Trying to write a PnP Power shell script to update Highlighted Content WP within a page

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, json-formatting, modern-pages

I am trying to build a Pnp PowerShell script that will update Highlighted Content webpart on a Modern SharePoint Online page from Grid View to List view.

I am using `Convertfrom-Json` and `Convertto-json`.

Everything looks to work for the script but when I go and refresh the SharePoint Page, it appears blank under that webpart. The plan is to eventually update all site pages containing HC webparts from Grid to List view.

```
$page= Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "TEST.aspx"
$webpart = $page.Controls | ? {$_.InstanceId -eq "<InstanceID of Specific HC webpart>"}
$WebpartJson= $webpart.PropertiesJson
$webpartobj = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $webpartJson
IF($webpartobj.layoutId -eq "Card") {

    $webpartobj.layoutId = "List"

}
$webpartJson = ConvertTo-Json $webpartobj -Compress
$webpart.PropertiesJson = $webpartJson
$page.Save()
$page.Publish()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmdlet you're looking for is [Set-PnPPageWebPart](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPPageWebPart.html). Here's an example of updating the property:

```
$wp = Get-PnPPageComponent -Page "Super-Awesome-Stuff.aspx" -InstanceId "75a66f66-a56e-4515-bf3a-628268bcbec3"
$props = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $wp.PropertiesJson
IF($props.layoutId -eq "Card") {
    $props.layoutId = "List"
    Set-PnPPageWebPart -Page "Super-Awesome-Stuff.aspx" -Identity "75a66f66-a56e-4515-bf3a-628268bcbec3" -PropertiesJson (ConvertTo-Json $props -Compress -Depth 10)
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank You!